# how to config spring logback set maxHistory for 1hour?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, logback

spring logback config: 1

here got maxHistory save the log for 1 day. but how to make it save 1 hour?

cause there have too many logs if saved 1 day and the disk is full just half day.

```
<appender name="APPLICATION" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${LOG_FILE}</file>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>${FILE_LOG_PATTERN}</pattern>
    </encoder>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>${LOG_FILE}.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
        <maxHistory>1</maxHistory>
        <maxFileSize>512MB</maxFileSize>
        <totalSizeCap>5GB</totalSizeCap>
    </rollingPolicy>
</appender>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
<fileNamePattern>${LOG_FILE}.%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH}.%i.log.zip</fileNamePattern>
```

it will roll log file **every hour** into a zip file.

This is NOT about `<maxHistory>`, but rolling log file every hour.